# Do squashed commits conflict with their original commits

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

Would the following scenario produce conflicts, that require manual resolution?

1. You submit a feature branch for PR, containing commits D, E.
2. While the PR is being reviewed, you continue working on that same feature branch locally, and add more commits F, G, H.
3. At some point, the PR is approved and merged into master. [Commits D/E on master have been replaced with commit X due to squashing](https://github.com/blog/2141-squash-your-commits). You now have a local branch containing commits D, E, F, G, H, and a master branch containing commit X.
4. You want to merge commits F/G/H into master. So you try to merge your local branch (containing D/E/F/G/H) into master (containing X).

Commits D/E and X touch the exact same lines of code, but have different commit IDs. If D/E is looked at together and compared with X, they are identical. But if D is looked at in isolation and compared with X, there are many differences between them, on commonly modified lines.

Is git smart enough to merge {D/E - X} without any merge conflicts? Or would the above produce a number of conflicts needing manual intervention?

Comment: Why don't you try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran some git experiments locally, replicating the workflow steps described in the question. Unfortunately, the answer seems to be yes. Using git squash will result in many merge conflicts, if you're not very careful of what you're doing.

I've written about this extensively in [this blog post](http://www.thecaucus.net/#/content/caucus/tech_blog/516).

---

The problem described above wouldn't have occurred if you did a naive merge, without any squashing. In that case, after the merge, both master and your local branch would contain commits D-E. Hence, the next time you try to merge your local D-E-F-G-H branch, git would simply execute the merge by applying F-G-H on top of master.

However, because we did the squash, this ends up confusing git. Instead of simply applying F-G-H on top of X, it instead tries to merge D-E-F-G-H together with X. Unfortunately, because commits F-G-H modify the same lines of code that are also modified by X, the resulting diff fails with a merge conflict.

Some potential ways to resolve this problem:

1. Brute force: Suck it up and resolve all the conflicts manually.
2. Once you've submitted a pull-request, do not develop any additional commits on top of the commits that are contained in the pull-request. Those commits in the pull-request are going to disappear, from git's perspective, so you don't want to depend on them. Unfortunately, this means that any refinements you want to do on top of what you had just submitted, will need to wait until your pull-request has been approved and merged.
3. If you've made refinements on top of an earlier pull-request, do not allow the earlier pull-request to get merged. Instead, submit a new pull-request with your updated branch, or overwrite the existing pull-request with all the refinements you've made. Unfortunately, this makes the pull-request process an all-or-nothing affair. Ideally, you might like to have the initial pull-request, and the additional refinements, to be approved/merged incrementally. Instead, to prevent the conflicts, you would have to force yourself to merge the whole thing in one shot, or not merge anything at all.
4. Suppose your earlier PR was merged, and you have new refinements that you now want to merge into master as well. Instead of trying to merge your entire branch into master, cherry-pick the incremental commits that you had created, and merge only those cherry-picked commits. So in the example given above, instead of trying to merge D-E-F-G-H into X, cherry pick commits F-G-H, apply them on top of X, and then create a pull-request with your resulting branch. This works well, avoiding all conflicts, and allowing you to do your dev work at any time/pace that you desire. Unfortunately, this also requires you to manually keep track of the fact that D-E == X, and that later commits F-G-H need to be manually cherry-picked and applied. This requires more time and cognitive effort on your part, and it's also easy to mess up this step by either cherry-picking too many commits (and producing conflicts anyway), or cherry-picking too few commits (and missing important changes).
5. Avoid using github's squash-on-megre functionality. Either squash all commits yourself locally, prior to submitting a pull-request. Or merge the pull-request without any squashing at all. This is the status-quo for most projects, with all the benefits/downsides that come with it.

As you can see, there is a real problem/cost associated with squashing all commits prior to merging, and none of the above solutions are perfect. I'm not sure which of the above is the least of all evils. But I did want to encourage you to think more deeply about this issue, and realize the caveats involved in taking advantage of this new awesome GitHub feature.

Comment: It's not the squash "merge" itself that causes the problem, but rather the fact that there's no merge at all.  Once your new work has been incorporated, you must rebase your `D-E-F-G-H` sequence into an `F'-G'-H'` sequence whose parent (`F'`'s parent, that is) is that new `X` commit.  Which is annoying, but do-able.  (This isn't specific to github, but a general principle with git: merge uses the *merge base* to compute diffs, and squash "merges" aren't merges at all, hence do not affect the merge base.)

Comment: I agree. What you're describing is conceptually similar to suggestion #4 above: manually pick the commits you want, and apply them on a new branch. Like you mentioned, it's doable, but it's unfortunate that the dev now needs to parse through his git log and start hunting for specific git-commits that he's interested in.

Answer (score 3):

Git compares the changes at each tip since the shared base.  Identical changes cause no conflict.